# TextArea in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, textarea, activex, webbrowser-control

I have a **WebBrowser** object that I use to navigate to a forum site. Now, I am filling a form that has a **textarea** I need to interact with.

When I finished writing the topic and submit the value of the **textarea**, the value didn't set to what I wanted.

```cs
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

browser.Navigate("www.example.com");

browser.Document.All["textarea"].InnerText = "MyText";

browser.Document.All["SubmitButton"].InvokeMember("Click");
```

Now that didn't work, and one more important thing.. When I use the HTML visualizer to see the page while debugging, The area of the textarea in the visualizer is not displayed it says "This program cannot display the webpage" but the rest of the page is displayed normally.

I heard something about **textarea** that it is an HTML5 element and because the **WebBrowser** is an activeX that use the Internet Explorer so maybe I have a version of Internet Explorer that not support textarea elements? I have IE 10.

Can someone please tell how to set the value of a **textarea** properly.

Comment: `textarea` is an old HTML form element; it's certainly not new to HTML5.

Comment: Ok so my theory it not right.. =[ at least one option is down.

Comment: Are you sure the website doesn't use some sort of WYSIWYG editor? Those often are represented by a `textarea` in the HTML, but then Javascript alters it.

Comment: You are right they are using WYSIWYG, I will try to shut it down..

Comment: That makes sense; most of those WYSIWYG editors inject an iFrame, which would explain why it is possible to get a "cannot display the webpage" error in that spot. Now, you have to figure out *why* you are getting an error.

Comment: I have an option to shut down the WYSIWYG so this is what I did  but my next problem is how to thank you :P

Comment: We would be able to help you so much more if you either share the HTML, or the page...